# Can the compiler/JIT optimize away short-circuit evaluation if there are no side-effects?

Tags: c#, micro-optimization, short-circuiting

I have a test which goes:

```
if(variable==SOME_CONSTANT || variable==OTHER_CONSTANT)
```

In this circumstances, on a platform where branching over the second test would take more cycles than simply doing it, would the optimizer be allowed to treat the `||` as a simple `|`?

Comment: What would stop them? If an expression *provably* has no side effects, then its (non)-evaluation cannot be observed, by definition. No language/runtime designer is masochistic enough to demand that code be emitted just in case intrepid developers check if it's really there. The trick is, of course, proving that there are no side effects, and here the compiler usually has to err on the side of caution.

Comment: One standard optimization strategy is to use a conditional move instead (CMOV instruction).  But the .NET optimizer tends to only do this in assignment expressions.  If they are true compile-time constants then the constant-folding optimization make the entire expression disappear.  This is where you can help out to make code more efficient, if you don't need short-circuiting then don't use it.  A poorly predicted lhs expression can make code x5 slower on Haswell, assuming a minimal if() statement body.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you say "Can the compiler..." are you asking if it would be allowed by the language (even if not yet implemented in any compiler), or are you asking if current C# compilers actually ever implement this optimization?

Comment: @BeeOnRope The former (though one of the answers states the latter is true as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In this circumstances, on a platform where branching over the second test would take more cycles than simply doing it, would the optimizer be allowed to treat the || as a simple |?

Yes, that is permitted, and in fact the C# compiler will perform this optimization in some cases on `&&` and `||`, reducing them to `&` and `|`. As you note, there must be no side effects of evaluating the right side.

Consult the compiler source code for the exact details of when the optimization is generated.

The compiler will also perform that optimization when the logical operation involves lifted-to-nullable operands. Consider for example

```
int? z = x + y;
```

where x and y are also nullable ints; this will be generated as

```
int? z;
int? temp1 = x;
int? temp2 = y;
z = temp1.HasValue & temp2.HasValue ? 
  new int?(temp1.GetValueOrDefault() + temp2.GetValueOrDefault()) :
  new int?();
```

Note that it's `&` and not `&&`. I knew that it is so fast to call `HasValue` that it would not be worth the extra branching logic to avoid it.

If you're interested in how I wrote the nullable arithmetic optimizer, I've written a detailed explanation of it here: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Answer (score 3):

Compilers are *allowed* to optimize short-circuit comparisons into asm that isn't two separate test & branch.  But sometimes it's not profitable (especially on x86 where compare-into-register takes multiple instructions), and sometimes compilers miss the optimization.

Or if compilers choose to make branchless code using a conditional-move, both conditions are always evaluated.  (This is of course only an option when there are no side-effects).

One special case is range-checks: compilers can transform `x > min && x < max` (especially when `min` and `max` are compile-time constants) into a single check.  This can be done with 2 instructions instead of branching on each condition separately.  Subtracting the low end of the range will wrap to a large unsigned number if the input was lower, so a subtract + unsigned-compare gives you a range check.

The range-check optimization is easy / well-known (by compiler developers), so I'd assume C# JIT and ahead-of-time compilers would do it, too.

To take a C example (which has the same short-circuit evaluation rules as C#):

```
int foo(int x, int a, int b) {
    if (10 < x && x < 100) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Compiled (with gcc7.3 `-O3` for the x86-64 Windows ABI, [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+Godbolt+targets+Linux+by+default%0A//+I+used+ms_abi+to+use+the+Windows+calling+convention+for+this+C%23+answer%0A//+comment+out+the+__attribute__+lines+for+compilers+that+don!'t+understand+them%0A%0A%23if+defined(_MSC_VER)+%7C%7C+!!defined(__x86_64__)%0A%23define+__attribute__(x)++/**/%0A%23endif%0A%0A%0A%0A__attribute__((ms_abi))%0Aint+foo(int+x,+int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++if+(10+%3C+x+%26%26+x+%3C+100)+%7B%0A++++++++return+a%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A__attribute__((ms_abi))+int+ext(void)%3B%0A__attribute__((ms_abi))%0Aint+bar(int+x)+%7B%0A++++if+(10+%3C+x+%26%26+x+%3C+100)+%7B%0A++++++++return+ext()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.31156930126002,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:100,l:'4',m:41.97136433558159,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:12.013321985979413,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'1',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ox',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),l:'4',m:46.015313678439,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:63.68843069873997,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).  You can see output for ICC, clang, or MSVC; or for gcc on ARM, MIPS, etc.):

```
foo(int, int, int):
    sub     ecx, 11        # x-11
    mov     eax, edx       # retval = a;
    cmp     ecx, 89
    cmovnb  eax, r8d       # retval = (x-11U) < 89U ? retval : b;
    ret
```

So the function is branchless, using `cmov` (conditional mov).  [@HansPassant says .NET's compiler only tends to do this for assignment operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929382/can-the-compiler-jit-optimize-away-short-circuit-evaluation-if-there-are-no-side#comment84866046_48929382), so maybe you'd only get that asm if you wrote it in the C# 
source as `retval = (10 < x && x < 100) ? a : b;`.

---

Or to take a branching example, we get the same optimization of the range check into a `sub` and then an unsigned compare/branch instead of compare/cmov.

```
int ext(void);
int bar(int x) {
    if (10 < x && x < 100) {
        return ext();
    }
    return 0;
}

  # gcc -O3
    sub     ecx, 11
    cmp     ecx, 88
    jbe     .L7             # jump if ((unsigned)x-11U) <= 88U
    xor     eax, eax        # return 0;
    ret
.L7:
    jmp     ext()           # tailcall ext()
```

IDK if existing C# implementations make this optimization the same way, but it's easy and valid for all possible inputs, so they should.

Godbolt doesn't have a C# compiler; if there is a convenient online C# compiler that shows you the asm, it would be interesting to try these functions there.  (I think they're valid C# syntax as well as valid C and valid C++).

---

### Other cases

Some cases other than range-checks can be profitable to optimize into a single branch or cmov on multiple conditions.  x86 can't compare into a register very efficiently (`xor`-zero / `cmp` / `setcc`), but in some cases you only need 0 / non-zero instead of a 0 / 1 boolean to combine later.  x86's `OR` instruction sets flags, so you can `or` / `jnz` to jump if *either* register was non-zero.  (But note that saving the `test reg,reg` before a `jcc` only saves code-size; macro-fusion works for test/jcc but not or/jcc, so or/test/jcc is the same number of uops as or/jcc.  It saves a uop with cmovcc or setcc, though.)

If branches predict perfectly, two `cmp` / `jcc` are probably still cheapest (because of macro-fusion: `cmp` / `jne` is a single uop on recent CPUs), but if not then two conditions together may well predict better, or be better with CMOV.

```
int foo(int x, int a, int b) {
    if ((a-10) || (x!=5)) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

[On Godbolt with gcc7.3, clang5.0, ICC18, and MSVC CL19](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZAagDiGAEaoGBeQSbFgmAoPkAZPCxEAPeSoCe8rADMmIjRwAMAQTnyAkvJGDMdHkAW0EAfSYVPC1UPwCtBEx5AHVTdFQAd0NkJgYGU2B5NBYAN0wWAjxUFnl7EgS8QwBhbgBmeVZBDMxiN08FNGDg8s1RTQJE%2BTCIggJiPBURAkxp%2BXyWTEM64iLUYIAHPAYewwmmTXSWMClNERYsYkFte4TMYL6Prla8eztMe1MgQgYQAsgBlJphABq2AASgBKeQcADsLVR8jAYAcgPQwLC5gAHAA2MJEgAs03hn1a2I2UxmcwWSxWYQg5kR8hkACouTJqeV8PYPh5hf1pudGYtltMoKEIlF4RzOQpunhiEE0FgALR6FggDpFBBMUzyVC/LghVAleQZQgIBqGO6DYYVQJ9UyaOqoCAe%2BTmUjyX1MAO%2BlSIlF8DzyaOB35QJha2iucOolFNeRszEcVoAEQArIqkcjI%2B4Y2X5MR9GIakxsyWyyic30y5WCNWrHWPsimx4vOCoen0psrjd5JgyjVUPtKsE8AAvJIcImuBNJpG57M5%2BSuJeuQMVWLIA6i32CBCiBjoMJTmfzlZEH0VP0hp/B/eaMNF%2BsxrzmLO5tcvQYbI9kOY5HnfWJZ0EQQCleU1pzwWc53OKoWGbGMfgzCBV2TIt0zZLUCxTb9ywrKtiBrTsoxjRsMOjVt2xUaj3DokV2NYr4sJ3DxxVmeYpRZWVwkiPBC19TBzAICASlQPB0CpVoSz4yVmRlCA5VExV3SfFQdEfTR2S/ejYwzNds3TSxuCJay/XXdMkzwiMTJbCiakk6TFNIose1LGNGMo7cWLYzjWgFH4%2BikeFGGkPMpFIPUpFceLUGkFpeH4eRhDECQkS%2BWh4oIaRksVUgAGsQFaIkADpWloWg8yJABOVpXFoLhl1cLgYqkMl4uCOhXFcBLipS6R4sEEBhqKpKotIOBYBgKAlogJBBjAnpyEodajh6EBgGRVpSABDQTkoFRRtIKIWB0axpAK0hnRGAB5FgGDuqQHqwYJWGAY5LvwStkEqMpJtm0hJMwZBmXu%2BKPUwBhLsZAbPrm5g2BQfh%2BEYBZJsgaKbzQsGtWe9otWSXIGHkLUfvEBBN0EMrrGYMrMAm0RxEkWhosRqQ4pG8HUqkQkiS1cl5GAZBkHkZFaozXBCHqNp6HkJpQN2nZlcRdK%2BF4QrRtKiq82G3m%2BtIAbHIF5LSCFiaptIGaSvmla1vV8CtogHbwJQdHgGN4aTuWR5zsu67bthx69hdAhXvegG3l%2B/7wcBqGQc2S7Ieh5YI/h3nreR2Ged%2BzGMt4HGVDxiACcQ6pidJ6mKbyanaeQenc0Z5mmFZ9mcq5nnYvixLraFkWxbJIpffkPNqtcGf5fwIhNfygM1YODW8taVptaxvWHYN6LEiYB5KGio2TekM2h7GqQ7em/eeq4fqQDzLhqtoAk6sOvMCQJJquDJVoTUrbX31rNaKC1lrwFWigN2m0KCe1gcQH2tAmqkjJMdI4QdJoQAuuDMOxAPoPSehUWOhD4rfUTpIZOapU54FBhncwUMYao3IK6POhV5gowKkXDGnBS4CHyBXeA1dKi12kCTcwPdOZ0H7nzQel0R7EjHvIfsDkmryC4G1ZE8hYQABVkjz0VkvOqK9EEby4NvfhoCSqn2fufXqT8AEz3/mSJqZJaBki4MiVweZgE23GkIe2js5oQOgV7OB21EEgDwFLd%2BGDTrBxwaHUw4cWHEJjm9D61sKFsCTtkmhwM6Hp3BpnZhD1c5I04YXRgxc%2BG6wEbjYRNsa4sDrmTRuVMaY6FbgzJmLM2ZCA5hIGRPV%2BZX38cLJR4sYnS3foYxeG8Varw2sYsklj6nWKigfTAR89pV3KnYnql8FEBMmnfMBsjH7mxAGSWWBJaBEgJB1dxSZkSNXoOM22e8LkHKJK0aqjyCQANcM1Akh0mpNWRD1Vo8jBYBOCaVXmVzPnwvvmUR4aEblAA)

gcc compiles it the obvious way, with 2 branches and a couple `mov` instructions.  clang5.0 spots the opportunity to transform it:

```
    # compiled for the x86-64 System V ABI this time: args in edi=x, esi=a, edx=b
    mov     eax, esi
    xor     eax, 10
    xor     edi, 5
    or      edi, eax        # flags set from edi=(a^10) | (x^5)
    cmovne  edx, esi        # edx = (edi!=0) ? a : b
    mov     eax, edx        # return edx
    ret
```

Other compilers need some hand-holding if you want them to emit code like this.  (And clang could use the same help to realize that it can use `lea` to copy-and-subtract instead of needing a `mov` before `xor` to avoid destroying an input that's needed later).

```
int should_optimize_to(int x, int a, int b) {
    // x!=10 fools compilers into missing the optimization
    if ((a-10) | (x-5)) {
        return a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

gcc, clang, msvc, and ICC all compile this to basically the same thing:

```
    # gcc7.3 -O3
    lea     eax, [rsi-10]      # eax = a-10
    sub     edi, 5             # x-=5
    or      eax, edi           # set flags
    mov     eax, edx
    cmovne  eax, esi
    ret
```

This is smarter than clang's code:  putting the `mov` to eax before the `cmov` creates instruction-level parallelism.  If `mov` has non-zero latency, that latency can happen in parallel with the latency of creating the flag input for `cmov`.

**If you want this kind of optimization, you usually have to hand-hold compilers toward it**.

Comment: To be fair, this "range check" trick is a specific case where the form of the check allows it to be simplified into a single check. If you assume the OP is asking about the more general case of checks (like the one he presented) that can't be reduced like that, the answer based on my testing is that at least on x86, they still prefer a series of jumps, even when none of the checks have side effects. Probably one reason is that x86 doens't have a great way to AND or OR the results of comparisons (bits in the flags reg) together, so a series of checks is usually the most efficient...

Comment: ... ignoring mis-predictions (indeed, due to macro-fusion, just doing the check is often about the same cost as the check plus the subsequent conditional jump).

Comment: @BeeOnRope: yeah definitely.  I was answering the "can" question, not "does it usually", partly as a counterexample to the wrong answer posted at the time saying it couldn't, and partly as a proof-of-concept that this can happen in cases where it's profitable.  I'm glad you posted an answer about it the tradeoff between branch prediction vs. compact asm because x86 can't easily compare into a register.  (Except when auto-vectorizing with AVX512; then masked compare into another mask is fantastic.)

Comment: I guess my claim is that the example given is not really one of "doing the second check in an unconditional manner despite using the shortcut operator" but rather "a transformation which removes one of the checks entirely", which is kind of a different thing. I'm actually interested in cases where a compiler actually keeps all the checks, but does them in a non-short-circuit manner, because I've looked for them before and haven't found one. BTW even if x86 could compare into a register (can ARM?) it would be awkward(ish): two compares, an OR then another compare and branch...

Comment: Ah I see.  That's a good point about range-checks being too special. It's legal and profitable for `x-10 || a==5` (and prob. other cases of multiple comparison for equality), but gcc/clang/MSVC/ICC miss that optimization (https://godbolt.org/g/74qpyn).  `OR` sets flags (but can't macro-fuse, so it only saves code-size to leave out the `test` before a `jcc`).

Comment: Good example with subtraction and OR to replace equality - it's a good case where the non-shortcut pattern is pretty reasonable. Even here "profitable" still depends on the probabilities: if for example the first `(a-10)` clause is usually true, the direct jmp seems better than the half dozen instructions. Still I agree there are probably sequences that are usually better. I don't think your examples are correct though, shouldn't `(x == 5)` translate to `!(x - 5)`?

Comment: @BeeOnRope: ah yes, `x != 5` is the trick.  With that bugfix, clang actually manages to transform `foo` into basically what I was hoping for, but using `xor` instead of non-destructive `lea`.

Comment: Interesting. Note that in your example, the body of the `if` is simple enough to be done branch-free too, so this gives the compiler more inventive to combine the conditions into a single check, since then the entire thing becomes a `cmov` on the final combined condition. In the more general case where the `if` can't/won't be done branch-free, the [calculation seems to change](https://godbolt.org/g/tsVKoG) and `clang` still choses two branches. `icc 18` however still combines the condition and uses a single jump. Huh...

Comment: Unfortunately for C#, the JIT doesn't optimize as much as it could because of time constraints (JIT compilation needs to be fast). Here's an [online compiler with your example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgZgARwIwDYUCYkGEkDeAsAFACQamAlgHbBIBmA9kwBS30AeANEh0mF78ARgEpCpJFKRkqDJK1QAGJAB4knJADItGtUmVLxxEtLMy4AdgEBuSdLIBfe1IrXhd8s5KOgA) which shows there's no conditional move. See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/7447).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Thanks for the update on actual C# JIT implementations.  Too bad it misses even the simple range-check.  Does C# have the option of using an ahead-of-time compiler, though?  And does it do a better job?

Comment: @PeterCordes well, there's [NGen](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator) which generates native code ahead of time, although I don't think it does a better job than the JIT - its main purpose is to avoid the delay incurred by calling the JIT. Then, there's [.NET Native](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/getting-started-with-net-native) although it's for UWP only, and I don't know how it performs. Finally, there's [LLILC](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc) which is a LLVM-based compiler, but it looks like it's dead :(

Comment: @PeterCordes oh, I almost forgot there's also a plan for a [tiered JIT](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4331) which could be promising.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the compiler *can* make that optimization. Indeed, every language of interest generally has an explicit or implicit "as if" type clause that makes such not-observable optimizations allowed without needing a specific rule for it. This allows is implement the checks in a non-shortcut manner, in addition to a whole host of more extreme optimizations, such as combining multiple conditions into one, eliminating the check entirely, implementing the check without any branch at all using predicated instructions, etc.

The other side, however, is that the specific optimization you mention of unconditionally performing the second check isn't performed very often on most common platforms because on many instruction sets the branching approach is the fastest, if you assume it doesn't change the predictability of the branch. For example, on `x86`, you can use `cmp` to compare a variable to a known value (as in your example), but the "result" ends up in the EFLAGs register (of which there is only one, architecturally). How do you implement the `||` in that case between the two comparison results? The second comparison will overwrite the flag set by the first, so you'll be stuck saving the flag somewhere, and then doing the second comparison, and then trying the "combine" the flags somehow just so you can do your single test<sup>1</sup>.

The truth is, ignoring prediction, the conditional branch is often almost free, especially when the compiler organizes it to be "not taken". For example, on x86, your condition could look like two `cmp` operations, each immediately followed by a jump over the code in the `if()` block. So just two branch instructions versus the hoops you'd have to jump though to reduce it to one. Going further - these `cmp` and subsequent branches often [macro-fuse](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/macro-operation_fusion) into a single operation that has about the same cost as the comparison alone (and take a single cycle). There are various caveats, but the overall assumption that "branching over the second test" will take much time is probably not well founded.

The *main* caveat is branch prediction. In the case that each individual clause is unpredictable, but where the whole condition is predictable, combining everything into a single branch can be very profitable. Imagine, for example, that in your `(variable==SOME_CONSTANT || variable==OTHER_CONSTANT)` that `variable` was equal to `SOME_CONSTANT` 50% of the time, and `OTHER_CONSTANT` 49% of the time. The `if` will thus be taken 99% of the time, but the first check `variable==SOME_CONSTANT` will be totally unpredictable: branching exactly half the time! In this case it would be a great idea to combine the checks, even at some cost, since the misprediction is expensive.

Now there are certain cases where the compiler can *combine* checks together simply due the form of the check. Peter shows [an example using a range-check like example in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48932858/149138), and there are others.

Here's an interesting one I stumbled across where your `SOME_CONSTANT` is 2 and `OTHER_CONSTANT` is 4:

```
void test(int a) {
    if (a == 2 || a == 4) {
        call();
    }
}
```

Both `clang` and `icc` implement this as a series of two checks and two branches, but recent `gcc` uses [another trick](https://godbolt.org/g/f4gKCH):

```
test(int, int):
  sub edi, 2
  and edi, -3
  je .L4
  rep ret
.L4:
  jmp call()
```

Essentially it subtracts 2 from `a` and then checks if any bit other than 0b10 is set. The values 2 and 4 are the only values accepted by that check. Interesting transformation! It's not that much better than the two branch approach, for predictable inputs, but for the *unpredictable clauses but predictable final outcome* case it will be a big win.

This isn't really a case of doing both checks unconditionally however: just a clever case of being able to combine multiple checks into fewer, possibly with a bit of math. So I don't know if it meets your criteria for a "yes, they actually do in practice" answer. Perhaps compilers *do* make this optimization, but I haven't seen it on x86. If it exists there it might only be triggered by profile-guided optimization, where the compiler has an idea of the probability of various clauses.

---

<sup>1</sup> On platforms with fast `cmov` two cmovs to implement `||` is probably not a terrible choice, and `&&` can be implemented similarly.